# Caching results pushed to a web site

Tags: batch-file, caching, restful-architecture

Is there a name for something that caches results that are pushed to another web site?

For example, a cache will locally store the results of a query (a `GET`) from a web site so that it only has to get the value once, making subsequent requests faster.

A reverse proxy will `GET` results from another server on behalf of a client.

What I am looking at is a mechanism that caches `PUT` requests to a restful server.

Imagine a system that carries out a batch update to a restful service (this is a legacy system). How it works currently is that every record for a resource is put into a batch file and the whole batch file is sent to a restful API. This is obviously very wasteful of bandwidth especially if most records do not change from one batch to the next.

I have designed a system that carries out a local comparison (it creates a hash value) for each record. If there is no change then it knows it does not need to `PUT` the record on the server. If there is a change it knows to send an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` to the server. (and it also knows how to handle `DELETEs`).

I don't know if this concept has a name. I have been calling it a 'reverse-cache'.

Has anyone come across this concept before?

Comment: It sounds like a version control.

Comment: I can see your point about 'version control' but the same would apply to a normal cache, you only want to 'pull down' a file that has changed (it's version) and use the local copy if it has not changed...